# FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: in HBase+Hive intergration

Tags: hbase, hive

Componet used:-
-Ubuntu 12.04, hive(0.9.0), hbase(0.94.3), hadoop(0.20.2)-single-node, zookeeper-3.4.3, guava-11.0.2, hive-hbase-handler-0.9.0

tutorials:-https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration

steps
1) start hadoop,
2) start hbase-master
3) start hiveserver
4) start hive shell using --auxpath parameters as in tutorial
 (all works without errors -    JobTracker,HRegionServer,HMaster,DataNode,NameNode,SecondaryNameNode,TaskTracker,HQuorumPeer,Jps)

```
hbase(main):001:0> status
1 servers, 0 dead, 2.0000 average load
```

On hive shell I create can create table as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS familia (id_familia INT,fk_veiculo INT,fk_cliente INT,nome STRING) ROW FORMAT delimited fields terminated by ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
load data local inpath '/home/trendwise/hive_data/tables_csv/familia.csv' overwrite into table familia;
```

but when I do below query,nothing shown,just cursor blinking.I waited for long time,then error shown

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_familia_1 (key int, id_familia int, fk_veiculo INT,fk_cliente INT,nome STRING)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key, cf1:id_familia, cf2:fk_veiculo,cf3:fk_cliente, cf4:nome")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_familia");
```

I did `list` on hbase shell,which didn't show any table what I tried ?

Error:-

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 10 times
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.getHBaseAdmin(HBaseStorageHandler.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:147)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:398)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:538)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3305)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:242)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:134)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1326)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1118)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:951)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:258)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:215)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:406)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:689)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:557)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
) FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
 <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
 <value>/home/trendwise/hadoop/hbase-0.94.3/hbase_dataDir</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
 <value>2222</value>
 <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
 </description>
</property>
<property>
 <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
 <value>localhost</value>
 <description></description>
</property>
<property>
 <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
 <value>true</value>
 <description></description>
</property>
```

Comment: Did you verify your HMaster is running using `jps`? And do you manage your own ZooKeeper instance? If not, you should not set all these ZooKeeper properties, you can just set `HBASE_MANAGES_ZK` in `$HBASE_HOME/conf/hbase-env.sh`.

Comment: @Pieterjan, HMaster is running after `jps`,but no HRegionServer & HQuorumPeer,Is these are such important ?.I am not managing my own ZooKeeper,so I uncomment `export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true` in hbase-env.sh & withdraw hbase.cluster.distributedhbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort,hbase.z ookeeper.quorum properties

Comment: That's correct. As long as HBase manages ZooKeeper there is no need for HRegionServer and HQuorumPeer to run, as far as I know. At lest that's the case in psuedo-distributed mode. After these changes you still get the same error? What does your log file say?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line that has "127.0.1.1" in your /etc/hosts file to "127.0.0.1" and restart everything. Also, copy hbase-site.xml into the HIVE_HOME/conf directory.

Comment: I did changes in /etc/hosts as
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 TrendwiseAnalytics
127.0.0.1 trendwise
#127.0.1.1 TrendwiseAnalytics

& copied hbase-site.xml,restart machine ,but remains same issue & in hive.log file

ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin (Log4JLogger.java:error(115)) - Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.core.resources" but it cannot be resolved.
WARN  client.ZooKeeperSaslClient (ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:<init>(123)) - SecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration occurred when trying to find JAAS configuration.

Comment: also when I am shutting down HBase master using stop-hbase.sh ,it take more time to stop & not shutting down.so close terminal & kill that process

Comment: these things indicate that your HBase is not running fine.Make sure that you have specified at least all the properties shown below in your hbase-site.xml file :hbase.rootdir, custer.distributed, hbase.zookeeper.quorum, hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort
hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir

Comment: all hadoop's components are running & for HBase-HMaster,HRegionServer,HQuorumPeer,running.but,it again gives error--> FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for  after 10 tries. 
I checked HRegionServer is running
Is my setting in above hbase-site.xml are correct ? mainly (hbase.rootdir=hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase,should I change 54310 to 90000)

Answer (score 0):

Hbase is not able to start all of its daemons...so u might get a clue in hbase logs...see if u can find anything in the hbase logs and report that error...hope this works...

Answer (score 0):

It seems Hive is not able to find the required jar files

Try to execute the command with all the

hive –auxpath /path-to-/hive-examples.jar;other jar files too seperated by semicolon

and then try putting the hbase conf file in hive conf directory.

and define aux path in hive-site.xml or in hive-env.sh and try

these error are mostly due to hive being not able to connect to hadoop or hbase.

and also check all the daemons are running of hbase and you can perform all the opoeration on hbase shell.